# Build multiple solutions in one single task (Azure DevOps Pipelines)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a Git Repository in Azure DevOps with 2 solutions (.sln) in separate folders. I'm building a pipeline that uses the "Visual Studio Build" to build those solutions and then extract somewhere else.

The problem is I don't want to have 2 separate tasks (one for each solution). I want to have one task that builds both of them in one run. I am aware that you can pass a search criteria with wildcards to search for the solutions, but in my case I have two specific paths to the solutions. Is it possible to specify a search criteria that will search for both the specific paths of the solutions?

Microsoft Docs Help:

[image: Microsoft Docs Help]

Pipeline specification:

[image: Pipeline specification]

Comment: I think you should be able to enter 2 paths separated by `;`.

Comment: So I tried it and got an error message like "Project file does not exist". Both paths are correct :( @jessehouwing

Comment: What are your two "specific paths"? Would they not fall under all subdirs like `"projects: '**/*.sln'"` (taken from my yaml pipeline)

Comment: Imagine I have 5 solutions scattered around the repository, but only want to build 2 of them using their specific paths within the repository. So I need a search criteria that searches for both solutions using their paths. The `**/*.sln` search criteria would bring me all of the solutions. @GetShifting

Answer (score 0):

You can use this syntax:
'**/@(solution1.sln|solution2.sln)'

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/file-matching-patterns?view=azure-devops